# Database: retrieve data before the end of query execution

Tags: sql, database, vertica

Can database return partial results like a stream before the end of query execution? i know for some queries with like `group by` or `order by` we may need all the information before building the result. But for simple `select`, is it possible for a database to return data whenever it finds any? If it is, will it still be possible with `JDBC`.

I'm using `Vertica`, but it's a general question. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is not a general question as the answer depends on the underlying database platform and possibly even the version. Then there is a second part which is does the data access tool support it and that *might* also depend on the database platform with which it is interacting.

Comment: @Igor of cause, what I mean is any information about this kind of operation is welcome, for example which database with which tool can do this.

Comment: I guess it depends on the capabilities of Vertica?? Does Vertica allow such functionality? I would guess probably not, because how would Vertica or any other database/data store know you need partial data? Your question doesn't make sense or is not very valuable.

Comment: @NightRider I don't need partial data, I need the ability to get data out without waiting for the whole result to be ready, for some simple query. Maybe it's already the case, I don't know, just asking.

Comment: how about caching the data instead of constantly retrieving it?

Comment: @NightRider I've said nothing about constantly retrieving the data, it could be a one-shot query.